# Dynamic Array Filling in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like to share a very bizzare phenomenon I am currently working on. Globally speaking, the task looks trivial as it is about filling some arrays. However after debugging several times my code, the error:
`Index was outside the bounds of the array` does not look as trivial as it looks, and I wonder if I miss something. I have hesitated before posting that thread to avoid any potential downvotes, but to be honest, this error is really weird to me, since all the defined variables retrieved from the debug mode matches my expectation.

**As an illustration:**

```
int count = FileNameFromPath.Length;
int i = 0;
while (i < count)
{
    try
    {
        string[] outp = new string[]
        {
        "CS_" + FileNameFromPath[i]
        }

        ;
        DataTable SourceData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(FileDirectory[i]);
        string[] SavePath = new string[]
        {
        DirOutputOlis + @"\" + outp[i]
        }

        ;
        CreateCSVFileFromDataTable(SourceData, SavePath[i]);
        Console.WriteLine("File Processed in Output Directory: {0}", outp[i]);
        i++;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exc)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(logPath, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Message :" + exc.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" + exc.StackTrace + "" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("File not Processed to Directory:  {0}", FileNameFromPath);
        PrintException(exc);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        goto Exitx;
    }
}
```

**I reiterate:** `outp`, `SourceData`, `SavePath`, `count=3` are all correct for `i=0`, but the problem starts at the following increment `i=1` in row `SavePath` even if for the latter case the former variables are correct too (from the debug mode).

Comment: Could you, please, *format* out the code (adjust indents, drop commented out fragments etc.)

Comment: `outp` only ever has one element since you define it that way. Your code is fundamentally confused. You probably mean `string outp`.

Comment: Your `phenomenon` can be debugged in 5 seconds. We can not debug code that we can not even build.

Comment: You should easily be able to see the problem if you *step through* your code in the debugger. As @JeroenMostert has pointed out, `outp` only ever has a single element, so `outp[i]` when `i != 0` will throw an exception.

Comment: `goto Exitx` are you kidding?

Comment: As others have mentioned, you're defining your arrays to only have 1 element. If you want to effectively store a list of filenames with some changes use a `List<string>` and the `Add` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like outp is defined as a 1-element array (so, only outp[0] is valid). If i > 0, you are accessing outside the array boundaries, hence the exception. Same applies to SavePath.

Since you want to have an array of elements, you can either

1. Declare outp/Savepath outside the while cycle, specifying the correct number of elements (once declared, arrays have fixed size)
2. Declare them as a List rather than Array. A List can be accessed via the [] operator, but also supports the .Add method allowing it to grow.

You could go with something like

```
List<string> outp = new List<string>();
List<string> SavePath = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < FileNameFromPath.Length; ++i)
{
    outp.Add("CS_" + FileNameFromPath[i]);
    SavePath.Add(DirOutputOlis + @"\" + outp[i]);
}
```

Comment: @`Marco`: You pinpoint the issue. my aim was to  make `outp` a 3-element array, likewise `SavePath` since the indexes for {0,1,2}.

Answer (score 1):

Step through your code here and imagine what happens with different values of `i`:

```
// outp is an array with a *single* element
string[] outp = new string[]
{
    "CS_" + FileNameFromPath[i]
};
DataTable SourceData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(FileDirectory[i]);
// SavePath is an array with a *single* element
string[] SavePath = new string[]
{
    DirOutputOlis + @"\" + outp[i]
};
CreateCSVFileFromDataTable(SourceData, SavePath[i]);
Console.WriteLine("File Processed in Output Directory: {0}", outp[i]);
i++;
```

Since `outp` and `SavePath` only have 1 element, you will get an exception when you try to index them when `i > 0`. It's not clearly exactly what you were trying to do there. If you don't actually need an array, then just use a string. So it would become:

```
string outp = "CS_" + FileNameFromPath[i];
```

and:

```
string SavePath = DirOutputOlis + @"\" + outp;
```

Or, if your intention was to store the values of `outp` and `SavePath`, then you need a collection defined outside of the while loop:

```
string[] outp = new string[count];
string[] SavePath = new string[count];
// ...
while (i < count)
{
    outp[i] = "CS_" + FileNameFromPath[i];
    // ...
    SavePath[i] = DirOutputOlis + @"\" + outp[i];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `@Matt & Marco`: Many Thanks for your prompt explanation. I appreciate.